# Angular cache loads outdated index.html file

Tags: angular, angular-service-worker

My application runs smoothly once it has loaded. However, the first time I try to load the application after a while, I get a white page. The console shows the error :
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () main.hash2.js:1`

(hashX is to be replaced with a regular hash)

When I check on the server, the main file is named main.hash3.js, which explains why the request failed (main.hash2.js is the name of the main file from the previous version of the application). My question is : Why did my app try to get the outdated main file rather than the new one ?

My ngsw.json looks like this :

```
{
    "configVersion": 1,
    "index": "/index.html",
    "assetGroups": [
      {
        "name": "app",
        "installMode": "prefetch",
        "updateMode": "prefetch",
        "urls": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html"
        ],
        "patterns": []
      },
      {
        "name": "assets",
        "installMode": "lazy",
        "updateMode": "prefetch",
        "urls": [
          "/assets/android-chrome-192x192.png",
          "/assets/apple-touch-icon.png",
          "..."
        ],
        "patterns": []
      }
    ],
    "dataGroups": [],
    "hashTable": {
      "/favicon.ico": "zerzeraezrazerazerz",
      "/index.html": "sqdfdezqreqqefrdddwfsfzqeff",
      "...": "..."
    },
    "navigationUrls": [
      {
        "positive": true,
        "regex": "^\\/.*$"
      },
      {
        "positive": false,
        "regex": "^\\/(?:.+\\/)?[^/]*\\.[^/]*$"
      },
      {
        "positive": false,
        "regex": "^\\/(?:.+\\/)?[^/]*__[^/]*$"
      },
      {
        "positive": false,
        "regex": "^\\/(?:.+\\/)?[^/]*__[^/]*\\/.*$"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Judging from [this tutorial](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-service-worker/), I thought that configuring the

I tried to change the "lazy" mode to "prefetch" in the "asset" group, then push my dist folder on my prod-like environnement. But when I tried to load my page on firefox, I got the error again. When I compare the index.html file in the browser and on the server, they are different.

I don't understand how to make sure my browser loads the up to date version each time.

Comment: Have You Configure to reload the Whole page when new  changes  occur in site

Comment: how do you do that ?

Comment: I updated answer i got resloved that cache issue when i configure like that

Answer (score 0):

1.import serverice worker and force to reload site when changes occur

2.app.component.ts

```
import { SwUpdate } from '@angular/service-worker';

constructor(
    updates: SwUpdate
  ) {
   
    if (updates.isEnabled) {
      updates.available.subscribe(() => {
        if (confirm('New version available. Load New Version?')) {
          window.location.reload();
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: I did something like that, but in a service, so it happens once the page is loaded (or not at all when loading fails)